# Braintree Subscription Payment Method Update Using Nonce From DropIn UI - 404 Not Found Error

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, braintree, nonce

Currently have a site utilizing PHP + JS SDK (via Drop-In UI), implementing the ability to update payment method for an existing subscription.

According to the current [PHP SDK Docs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+php/sdk/server/recurring-billing/update#updateable-fields), one of the fields that can be updated for a subscription is paymentMethodToken, which can be passed

> by token or payment method nonce

However, after making this call (confirming I have a valid subscription ID), a `Braintree_Exception_NotFound()` error is thrown. Per [Payment Method Documentation](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+php/sdk/server/payment-method-management/search#single-payment-method), this exception is thrown when a payment method cannot be located.

This suggests to me that the API does not allow for using nonce when updating subscription payment method. Am I missing something, or is the documentation just not up-to-date?

P.S. I've reviewed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28320119/4375304) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24977463/cannot-create-subscription-using-braintree-payment-nonce) (along w/ a few other unanswered), neither of which quite hit the mark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>I work at Braintree. The docs currently aren't clear on this point; I'll make sure they're corrected. Thanks for helping us find the problem. If you have more questions, feel free to [reach out to our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

You need to pass the nonce as `paymentMethodNonce` not as `paymentMethodToken`.

Comment: Ah, just beat me to it! I was just going to update to say I'd spoken to someone in support who reflected this very thing. Thanks!

Comment: Braintree haven't yet updated their documentation for PHP - https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/subscription/update/php - I've emailed them so I hope they add it as this tripped me up.